# jqGrid - modal forms for custom operations

Tags: forms, jqgrid, modal-dialog

In most of my grids, if I want to perform a "custom operation" that displays some data in a jqGrid modal form and allow the users to click "submit" to do something, I am able to simply leverage the existing "Edit" operation and tweak it to my needs.

However, I am working on a grid where the Add, Edit, and Delete operations are all in use, and I need an additional "custom operation" that opens a jqGrid modal form to display a couple of the columns along with a submit button to send the key ID to the target URL.

Normally this is very easy to simply re-task the Edit function, but since Edit is in use, I'm not sure how to do this.  Does jqGrid have a proper method for creating new custom operations that display modal forms just like Edit does?

Comment: do you need this dialog for all rows in your grid?

Comment: The custom modal form data would be based on the selected row (just like the NavGrid Edit).  The user would select the row, click the "custom button" down in the NavGrid, and a jqGrid Modal Form would appear with a couple of the columns in read-only mode, and a Submit button

Comment: I can suggest you a solution that get your form from server by row id. Is it good enough solution for you?

Comment: Sounds like that might work.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I was not able to find a way to do this through "core" jqGrid features and ended up simply adding a new button to the grid which opens my own custom modal box.

The multi-select features of jqGrid were also used to allow the user to select multiple records to be passed off to this custom function when the new button is clicked.

Here was the code for adding the button to jqGrid.  The AJAX call retrieves the HTML content for the modal that is being populated (in JSON format):

```
        .navButtonAdd('#listAllSupplierPurchasesGridPager', {
        caption: "Mark Paid",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-add",
        onClickButton: function () {

            var s;
            s = $("#listAllSupplierPurchasesGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');

            if (s.length > 0) {
                // Make AJAX call to get the dynamic form content
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/TargetItems/MarkPurchasesPaidRequest",
                    data: {
                        PurchaseIds: JSON.stringify(s)
                    },
                    success: function (content) {
                        // Add the content to the div
                        $('#MarkPurchasePaidModal').html(content);
                        // Display the modal
                        $("#MarkPurchasePaidModal").dialog("open");
                    },
                    error: function (res, status, exception) {
                        alert(status + ": " + exception);
                    },
                    modal: true
                });
            }
        },
        position: "first"
    })
```

The jQuery for setting up the basic modal box:

```
        $("#MarkPurchasePaidModal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 768,
        autoheight: true,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 250
        },
        modal: true
    });
```

And the div HTML to hold the modal:

```
<div id="MarkPurchasePaidModal" role="dialog" title="Mark Purchases Paid" class="container"></div>
```